# Django session partially expired

Tags: django, session-cookies

I have a problem when using Django.I set :

```
session_expire_at_browser_close = true
```

So,When a user close the browser,his session expire.
Now I also record times of try to login in session.

```
request.session['try_times'] += 1
```

If a user try to many times,the website will ask for a verification code.
But because of the setting above,the session expire after restart the browser.
Is any method can meet the two requirements above at the same time?
That is to say,when the browser is closed,a user should be logout,and the 'try_times' should not be deleted.

Comment: If you store `try_times` in the session, the user can delete their session cookie and reset it to zero. If you want to avoid this, you should store `try_times` on the server.

Comment: I know what is your means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can try to record the try_times on your server.